# When a QPushButton is clicked, it fires twice

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton

I used PyQt5 for a project and have the following snippet (`button` is a QPushButton)

```
def on_receive(self, query):
    print("receiving", query)
    datapackages = json.loads(query)

    for button, datapackage in zip(self.buttonArray, datapackages):
        self.wire_up_button(datapackage, button) 

def wire_up_button(self, datapackage, button):
    title, songid = datapackage["title"], datapackage["songid"]
    button.setText(title + " (" + str(datapackage["votes"]) + ")")
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.upvote(songid))

def upvote(self, sid):
    text = '{"action":"upvote", "value":"' + sid + '"}\n'
    print(text)
    self.send(text)

def send(self, text):
    print("Sending")
```

The `on_receive` function is connected to a soccet client and will be called wheneever a data package is received. The layout is a bit complicated because my UI has so many buttons it's handier to iterate over them than to hard-code every single one.

Whenever I click the button, the wire-up function wires the button to the upvote function, which creates a json protocl and sends it to the socket server. However, the wireup-function is called **twice** per click. (I am certain of this because of the debug print commands). There is no other call in the send function in my program.

I speculate that this might be due to how clicked.connect works (maybe it fires upon click **and** release).

I used the QtDesigner to create the UI and loaded the `.uic` in my `main.py`

Comment: please, could you add more context, like where is located the `connect` signal line ? by seeing `songid` it seems to be inside a function

Comment: @PRMoureu I've done so, it might obfuscate what's going on there a bit. I tried my best to make it as readable as possible...

Comment: does upvote() called with the same sid? Are you sure that you don't call wire_up_button for same button twice?

Comment: oh, wire_up is called twice. does self.buttonArray contain duplicate buttons? how do you create it?

Comment: @ingvar It doesn't. I created it by hard-coding (just stuffing all the objects in one array manually). [Link to the full source](https://github.com/Pentabyteman/muscom/blob/master/pyqt_client/main.py)

Comment: will it work with `try: button.clicked.disconnect() except Exception: pass` inside `wire_up_button` (before .clicked.connect)?

Comment: @ingvar sorry, wireup isn't called twice per button. I'm bad at maths ;). It is only the upvote and send function that are being called twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156745/discussion-between-ingvar-and-narusan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you receive anything from socket you do

```
for button, datapackage in zip(self.buttonArray, datapackages):
    self.wire_up_button(datapackage, button)
```

and in `self.wire_up_button` you connect to button clicked event. Note, that `self.buttonArray` is always the same list of buttons, so every time `on_receive` is called you add 1 new subscription to each button click. But previous subscription to button click still exists, so on button click `upvote` will be called multiple times with different `sid`. You need to disconnect from button click event before adding new one:

```
def wire_up_button(self, datapackage, button):
    try:
        button.clicked.disconnect()
    except:
        pass
    title, songid = datapackage["title"], datapackage["songid"]
    button.setText(title + " (" + str(datapackage["votes"]) + ")")
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.upvote(songid))
```

`try ... except` block is required, because `button.clicked.disconnect()` raises exception if no functions were connected to click event.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had buttons with the `clicked` event firing twice, and this was fixed by the very simple step of **remembering to add the `@pyqtSlot` decorator**!

`QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName` was being called only once, in the Ui script created by `pyuic`, but with this code:

```
def on_testBtn_clicked(self):
    print('on_testBtn_clicked')
```

the clicked event on `QPushButton` named `testBtn` was called twice. With this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

@pyqtSlot()
def on_testBtn_clicked(self):
    log.debug('on_testBtn_clicked')
```

it correctly was only called once.

`self.testBtn.dumpObjectInfo()` may be useful to check how many slots are connected. Without the decorator I got:

```
OBJECT QPushButton::testBtn
  SIGNALS OUT
        signal: destroyed(QObject*)
          <functor or function pointer>
          --> PyQtSlotProxy::unnamed disable()
          --> PyQtSlotProxy::unnamed disable()
        signal: clicked(bool)
          --> PyQtSlotProxy::unnamed unislot()
          --> PyQtSlotProxy::unnamed unislot()
  SIGNALS IN
        <None>
```

With the decorator:

```
OBJECT QPushButton::testBtn
  SIGNALS OUT
        signal: destroyed(QObject*)
          <functor or function pointer>
        signal: clicked(bool)
          --> MainWindow::MainWindow on_testBtn_clicked()
  SIGNALS IN
        <None>
```